# jQuery selector for setting a value of an input based on the current context

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have several inputs that I would like to offer the same jQuery Autocomplete function on.

When the user selects an option, I would like to set the value of the corresponding text box to the id of the selection.

```
<script>
      $(function () {
          $(".batter").autocomplete({
              source: function (request, response) {
                  $.ajax({
                      url: "getplayersAjax.aspx",
                      dataType: "jsonp",
                      data: {
                          term: request.term,
                          league: 11
                      },
                      delay: 400,
                      success: function (data) {
                          response(data);
                      }
                  });
              },
              minLength: 3,
              select: function (event, ui) {
                  $("#birds1id").val(ui.item.id);
              }
          });
      });
  </script>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <input id="birds1" class="batter"><input type="text" id="birds1id" />
</div>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <input id="birds2" class="batter"><input type="text" id="birds2id" />
</div>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <input id="birds3" class="batter"><input type="text" id="birds3id" />
</div>
```

The code works fine for the birds1/birds1id pair.

However, I am struggling to work out how to get the function to work for the second birds2/birds2id pair (and other pairs that I will add later) without having to replicate the autocomplete function.

I assume the #birds1id selector needs to be replaced with something more generic but I am at a loss as to how to do it. [jQuery beginner here] I tried using 'this' but couldn't seem to get it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that you need to replace the hard-coded `#birds1id` selector. You can obtain a reference to the changed input from the `event` object that is the the first argument to your `select` handler: `event.target`. Once you have the element, you can query for its sibling and set the value. Note: I would think you need to use `ui.item.value` to get the value, rather than the `ui.item.id` you have in your code, but maybe I am wrong. The `success` handler becomes:

```
function(event, ui) {
  const $target = $(event.target);
  const $sibling = $target.next();

  $sibling.val(ui.item.value);  
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/qj3pm92b/) is a fiddle for reference.

Comment: The code change works! Thanks. I assume the .next() function moves to the next object in the DOM model so I will be sure to keep my second input next to the adjacent pair.

Comment: @redaxe: Yes, [.next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) gets the immediate sibling, so it is very much dependent on your HTML structure remaining as is. For a solution that doesn't constrain your HTML, you could try using data-attributes. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/ha09g76o/